# In Marionette, how do I send a message from view function to router?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using Browserify (kind of like AMD)

In view event handler, after password is verified, I'd like to send a message 'login_success' to router to change route.

In the route 'login_success' handler, I'd like to call route.navigate('/newRoute'), which is function extended from Backbone.

But I haven't figure out how to send message from view to router. Can anybody share a sample code or a link?

Is there any best practice to change route in Backbone?

Thanks!

Comment: use backbone.wreqr built into marionette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way is just use [Backbone.history.navigate()](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) .

If you rather have some local authority for navigation you could do something as

```
App.execute("navigate:to", "/url")
```

and implement it as you see fit:

```
App.commands.setHandler("navigate:to", function(url){
    ...
    Backbone.history.navigate(url)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the short answer. I like it since it is short. If I didn't set handler, will there be an error (undefined)? can multiple handler exist for the same event?

Comment: No. This is the main difference between a command and an event - a command is a single service the application provides. Only a single entity in the application may fulfill it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like to go the route of triggering an event that your router is listening to and then acts upon.

So say in your view you could say

```
onPasswordVerified: function() {
  this.trigger "password:verified"
}
```

Then in the controller you can listen to that event (note sometimes this is prefaced with childview depending on if you are listening to a collection/composite view, but I doubt you are with a login page):

```
this.listenTo(loginView, "password:verified", function(args) {
  App.vent.trigger "password:verified"
});
```

Lastly in your router you listen to that event (I usually build a `navigate` function into my App object which does `Backbone.history.navigate` in the background):

```
App.vent.on "password:verified", function() {
    App.navigate("/users");
    API.userProfile();
}
```

The great thing about this is if there are other parts of your app that should listen to this event, they can then act accordingly. Also routing this way lets you update your url/route to the page as if you'd done a `Backbone.history.navigate({trigger: true})` just without the associated 'refresh the page' server call.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this issue. the @listenTo you mentioned is in the Router or view? how does the router knows about the App? They totally seperated.

Comment: btw, I don't know coffee script yet, but the 'function' triggered a compiling error when I converting it to javascript.

Comment: Haha yea I was actually reversing my app to javascript (it's been ages since I've written in it) from coffeescript. @ just means this in coffeescript so @listenTo is really this.listenTo. Let me update the javascript a bit.

Comment: Oh and the @listenTo would be in the controller (assuming you're using controllers). if you aren't using controllers you could just do a App.vent.trigger within the view itself instead of the this.trigger piece first to bubble up the event